# Is it fine to use a navigation breadcrumb in the bottom of the page?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I am studying the importance of breadcrumbs for seo + in addition to user navigation experience.

I read https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/breadcrumb#html

but could not find there any information if the breadcrumb should be present on top of the page like a menu or submenu or it is ok to be in the bottom as well.

I have some hierachy like products -> germany -> berlin -> wedding for example and can nicely show this in a breadcrumb so the user can navigate and go higher in the chain with one click.

I don't want this on top of the page though but I want to put it in the bottom.

My concern is that google might interpret this as a fishy thing and penalise the seo.

So the question is:
Can we include a breadcrumb anywhere in the page even in the bottom where you need to scroll to see it or doing so and having the json ld schema might make search engine bots penalise the page?

Comment: Are you just concerned about SEO and not about usability?

Comment: For SEO, are you trying to get breadcrumb rich snippets in the search results

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes I am trying to do that and also make google understand what is the "cornerstone" article to get most of the juice. Google understands the structured data (I test it with their tool) but it doesn't show the breadcrumb in the search results...

Comment: When [Yoast talks about cornerstone content, they don't mention breadcrumbs at all](https://yoast.com/what-is-cornerstone-content/).  I'm not sure how you are trying to use breadcrumbs to make an article prominent.

Comment: Maybe I got the concept wrong but I do see a lot of pages doing this successfully. Like having a "Swimming products" page that shows on top of search when people search for "swimming products" and also they have other pages like swimming products in germany, in berlin, in wedding-berlin-germany etc. They connect these with breadcrumbs to swimming-products all the way up the hierarchy and make the main one show on top

Comment: I see, you are using breadcrumbs from sub-pages to link back to the main page.

Comment: I just started doing this as noticed that other pages do this and bring to top of search results the main page while in my case I have trouble because sub-categories show randomly for the main example keyword "swimming products"... I get top page swimming products in berlin etc while I want the main page to show

Answer (score 2):

To find a definitive answer is difficult, but I can't see Google penalising a website for using breadcrumbs in the footer. In fact, Apple is currently using that method on their website as shown below:

[image]

Now, it would be brave to argue against Apple, but that approach is uncommon. The average user would look above the content and towards the header if they're searching for breadcrumbs.

For a more thorough answer on the UX implications, I would ask on the [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.